# Request to merge two math.stackexchange accounts into one

Tags: support, user-accounts

could you please merge my two accounts on math.stackexchange into one?

My first account is authorised via google: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/18855/aleksey-pichugin

My second account is authorised via openid: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/18757/aleksey-pichugin

I would like to use the google login in the future, so could you please, if at all possible, merge the second account into the first (18757 into 18855).

Answer (score 6):

All taken care of :)

In the future, if you have trouble logging in or with accidentally creating multiple accounts, you can flag one of your posts for moderator attention; posting on meta is fine, but not necessary.

Comment: Many thanks! I did so because I saw someone else doing the same in the past. Won't happen again.

Answer (score 0):

I am faced with a similar situation.
Here is a link to my previous account: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/13621/sabyasachi-mukherjee

I did not have a second login option and when I deleted my gmail  account corresponding to that one, I lost access to it.

I therefore request the moderator to merge this one with it.I should have informed you earlier.In case you do merge them,please change my name showing up from Hermit to Sabyasachi Mukherjee.I would like to use the email id corresponding to Hermit to login.
Thank you.I won't pester you again after this with a similar problem.I have the same problem on physics.stackexchange.Will that be automatically corrected as well?

Comment: Hi Sabyasachi, I have merged your accounts! It's not pestering to request something that is part of the job of the moderators, I am happy to help :) Please don't hesitate to flag a post (see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/faq#flagging)) if you want to contact the moderators, or post on meta if you have a question about how the site works.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: This really isn't an answer.  It should probably be a comment under Zev's answer.

Comment: I now understand.I was following up, but I think that should not be done unless it is really an answer to the question posed by the asker.Right?